# BindingFailure in deserializing via JSON.Net 4.0 r3

Tags: clr, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string that was serialized by JSON.Net 4.0 r3 itself. The settings are the same for serialization and deserialization. The following exception occurs:

> Could not find type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Drawing.PointF,
>   System.Drawing]]' in assembly '"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"'

After turning on "stop when BindingFailure is thrown", I see the problem is in the following part (JSON.Net source code, DefaultSerializationBinder.cs):

```
  if (assemblyName != null)
  {
    Assembly assembly;

#if !SILVERLIGHT && !PocketPC
    // look, I don't like using obsolete methods as much as you do but this is the only way
    // Assembly.Load won't check the GAC for a partial name
#pragma warning disable 618,612
    assembly = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(assemblyName);
#pragma warning restore 618,612
#else
    assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
 #endif

    if (assembly == null)
      throw new JsonSerializationException("Could not load assembly '{0}'.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, assemblyName));

    Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName); // BindingFailure here
    if (type == null)
      throw new JsonSerializationException("Could not find type '{0}' in assembly '{1}'.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, typeName, assembly.FullName));
  }
```

The error shown at the point of BindingFailure is

> The assembly with display name 'System.Drawing' failed to load in the
>   'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of
>   the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.Drawing' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

The operating system is Windows 7, 64-bit. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and targeting this application for Framework v4. The target is not Silverlight or PocketPC.

Why would it fail to load "System.Drawing" in this case? Where should I start investigating whether this is a JSON.Net issue or a problem with my Framework 4.0 installation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue is related to JSON.Net. I used to use the following setting

```
jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
```

This was because of a suggestion in a post (that involved deserializing generic collections like List). It was suggested that full type information would help with JSon.Net errors about the "Cannot instantiate abstract base classes" error message.

If I change it to

```
jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
};
```

it works fine. Interestingly, some type information does not get emitted, I do not get the BindingFailure and the deserialization works fine. I have no idea why it did not work with "Auto" in the first place.